# Duplicating SQLite store

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I am attempting to implement writeSafelyToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:error: on subclass of NSPersistentDocument. I have to handle NSAutosaveElsewhereOperation condition, which is effectively a duplicate operation of SQLite store.

The following code has an issue as it creates a duplicate store, but the store is actually empty and I cannot figure out why. I noticed the issue when I used "Revert Document" option, but it became clear when I tried using "Duplicate" menu item.

Basically, I am trying to remove current store, so it does not get saved. Then I add temp store, save context, remove temp store and add original store back.

```
if (inSaveOperation == NSAutosaveElsewhereOperation) {
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [[self managedObjectContext] persistentStoreCoordinator];
    id tempStore = [coordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:@"SQLite" configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:outError];
    success = (tempStore != nil);
    id originalStore = [coordinator persistentStoreForURL:originalStoreURL];
    success = success && 
        [coordinator removePersistentStore:originalStore error:outError];

    success = success && 
        [[self managedObjectContext] save:outError];

    // restore original store
    success = success && 
        [coordinator removePersistentStore:tempStore error:outError];
    success = success && 
        [self configurePersistentStoreCoordinatorForURL:originalStoreURL ofType:inTypeName modelConfiguration:nil storeOptions:nil error:nil];
```

Comment: My current understanding of NSAutosaveElsewhereOperation is not (only) a duplication. It happends after a AutoSave as long as the document has not a location yet.
I see at the moment two use cases when this occur (1) after new document which is not saved yet and (2) after a duplicate of an existing document

Answer (score 0):

because you try to seve the store in the Application folder, which happens to be readonly.
I think you should switch do the Documents folder.

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *docsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: It is definitely not an Application folder. I have some NSLog code that prints something like /private/var/folders/4z/7bzwcw5915g29x1363xhhfm40000gp/T/TemporaryItems
inSaveOperation is triggered by AutoSave, so I don't choose the location.